# How can I drag the mouse on a map to navigate it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, draggable

I am making a map game in unity. I want to drag the mouse on the map resulting in the player viewing different areas of the map (yes, like Hears of Iron IV). I have tried using the 'onDrag' method but I can not find the proper code for it. Can someone please link some documentation or required code for this method?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change camera position you can simply do it with this code:

```
public float dragSpeed = 2;
private Vector3 dragOrigin;


void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        dragOrigin = Input.mousePosition;
        return;
    }

    if (!Input.GetMouseButton(0)) return;

    Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(dragOrigin - Input.mousePosition);
    Vector3 move = new Vector3(pos.x * dragSpeed, 0, pos.y * dragSpeed);

    transform.Translate(move, Space.World);
}
```

With this, you can start and do other things.

If you want to move the map instead of the camera you can also try :

```
 private bool isDragging;

public void OnMouseDown()
{
    isDragging = true;
}

public void OnMouseUp()
{
    isDragging = false;
}

void Update()
{
    if (isDragging) {
        Vector2 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
        transform.Translate(mousePosition);
    }
}
```

this work as **Drag and Drop** any 2d objects in unity.

Answer (score 0):

the other answer does not work since the map should also move while button is held.. here is the fix

```
    public float dragSpeed = 2;
    private Vector3 dragOrigin;
    private bool dragStarted = false;

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
    {
        dragOrigin = Input.mousePosition;
        dragStarted = true;
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
    {
        dragStarted = false;
        return;
    }

    if (dragStarted)
    {
        Vector3 pos = main_camera.ScreenToViewportPoint(dragOrigin - Input.mousePosition);
        Vector3 move = new Vector3(pos.x * dragSpeed, 0, pos.y * dragSpeed);
        main_camera.transform.Translate(move, Space.World);
    }
```

this also assumes your camera is pointed downwards or facing north..